# Camera is offset from path it is following

Tags: camera, constraints, path, origin

The camera is constrained to follow a path, and both the path and the camera are far from the origin of the scene. I can see that the camera is being offset from the path with the same offset it had from the origin of the scene, but I don't know how to reset that.

Comment: also, ALT-O will clear the origin of the parented object (to the parent's one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to reset the location of an object. Alternatively, you can just set the location coordinates to zero in the <kbd>N</kbd> panel:

[image]